# Azure Storage - Proxy Setting in Java Code

Tags: java, azure, proxy, storage

In a java service, I'm trying to upload a file in an azure storage directory; therefore I've written a code like this :

```
import com.azure.core.util.*;
import com.azure.storage.file.share.*;
import com.azure.storage.file.share.models.*;

 //Create connexion string
String connectStr ="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=" + accountName + ";AccountKey=" + accountKey + ";EndpointSuffix=" + endpoint;
            
//ShareDirectoryClient
            
ShareDirectoryClient dirClient = new     ShareFileClientBuilder().connectionString(connectStr).shareName(shareName).resourcePath(directoryName).configuration(proxyOptions).buildDirectoryClient();
            
// Create empty file
dirClient.createFile(fileName, body.length());
```

The HTTPS request must goes through a proxy server, so, I get this error :

"Could not run 'sendFileInDirectoryProxyTest'
reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information: "

I can't set/use a global setting.
To set a proxy in the Java code, I've tried several things, like using the Configuration Class :

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.put("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
configuration.put("https.proxyHost", "xxxxxxxxx");
configuration.put("https.proxyPort", "xxxx");
            
ShareDirectoryClient dirClient = new     ShareFileClientBuilder().connectionString(connectStr).shareName(shareName).resourcePath(directoryName).configuration(configuration).buildDirectoryClient();
```

But it did not solve the issue.
I'm sure it is pretty simple, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks. Charles de Saint Andre.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure ProxyOptions and set them on the httpClientBuilder. All our Storage client builders have a .httpClient() method that accepts a client, and you can build a client with all defaults + the proxy options using a NettyAsyncClientBuilder(), which has a .proxyOptions() method. Please give that a try and let me know if you have any more issues.
Sample : [azure-sdk-for-java/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob at main · Azure/azure-sdk-for-java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob#set-a-proxy-when-building-a-client) (github.com)